# PATH variable showing different values (command prompt vs environment variables dialog box)

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, path

My Windows 7 PATH variable shows different content weather I enter the `PATH` command in the command prompt or weather I go through the environment variables dialog box. More over, the `PATH` variable seems to be duplicated at some time.

PATH variable @ the command prompt:

```
 1 C:\soft\Python27\;
 2 C:\soft\Python27\Scripts;
 3 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
 4 C:\Windows\system32;
 5 C:\Windows;
 6 C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
 7 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
 8 C:\Anaconda;
 9 C:\Anaconda\Scripts;
10 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;
11 C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
12 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;
13 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;
14 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\polyspace\bin;
15 C:\soft\Python27\;
16 C:\soft\Python27\Scripts;
17 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
18 C:\Windows\system32;
19 C:\Windows;
20 C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
21 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
22 C:\Anaconda;
23 C:\Anaconda\Scripts;
24 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;
25 C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
26 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;
27 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;
28 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\polyspace\bin;
29 K:\sw\Git\cmd;
```

PATH variable @ through the environment variables dialog box

```
 1 C:\soft\Python27\;
 2 C:\soft\Python27\Scripts;
 3 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
 4 C:\Windows\system32;
 5 C:\Windows;
 6 C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
 7 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
 8 C:\Anaconda;
 9 C:\Anaconda\Scripts;
10 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;
11 C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;
12 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;
13 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;
14 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\polyspace\bin;
15 K:\sw\Git\cmd;
```

At the command prompt, the first 14 entries are duplicated.

Question: how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sets of environment variables: user and system:

[image: Environment variable dialog window]

The system variables are the same for all users on the machine,
and require Administrator privilege to change. 
The user variables are individual to each user,
and can be altered freely by the user.

For most variables, if there are a system variable and a user variable
with the same name, the user variable simply overrides the system one. 
But `PATH` is a special case — the value of the variable that is set in CMD
is the user variable *appended to* (the end of) the system variable
(with a semicolon (`;`) interjected, if necessary).

It looks like you made a common error —
you copied your *complete* `PATH` value
into the space for your *individual* `PATH` variable
in the environment variables dialog box. 
(Or perhaps some buggy program did this for you.) 
This resulted in the system `PATH` value being duplicated
in your individual `PATH` variable,
so now you get the combined / duplicated value
whenever you start a Command Prompt process. 
The solution is simply to edit your individual `PATH` variable
to remove the first 14 entries (i.e., everything but `K:\sw\Git\cmd`). 
Those 14 directory names are in the system `PATH` value,
so you will still get them in your `PATH` value (but only once).